rental agreement tenant rental agreement adding a tenant
i started renting an house 5 years ago with my wife, 2 months ago mmy wife moved out and i had my mother move in, since was a new tenant moving in on my contract she had to sign the rental agreement so we were given a contract and we both signed it. a few days ago i was given a 30 day eviction notice to vacate for late rent and accumulation of stuff in the yard. i confronted manager and told him iv since ive lived there 5 years i am protected  by the tenant protection act of 2019 the manager said no this is a new contract the old contract is null and void so im not protected by the TPA and he can give me a 30 day notice instead of 60 day basically hes saying the 5 years ive lived at my house was erased and the new contract stands but i only added my mom on the rental agreement i didnt move then come back ive continuously lived there for 5 yeats can he do that

This site doesn't provide legal advice to uswrs; you need to talk to a lawyer about that. It does, however, offer answers to questions about hypothetical situations that occur to hypothetical people.

You are obviously familiar with the Tenant Protection Act of 2019, I recommend you add the section pertaining to the 5 years and ask for a generic interpretation as it pertains to date of the latest contract vs date of residency.  You might get a useful answer...

Presumably the question is whether you need to be given 30 days or 60 days notice.
